# Mean value theorem in several variables & Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I get stucked with an inequality using the mean value theorem in several variables.

Essentialy the theorem states that if a function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous on an interval $[x,y]$ then there exist $c \in [a,b]$ s.t.

$$f(y)-f(x)= \nabla f (c) \cdot (y-x)$$

Where the dot represent the dot product. But then I found that by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality it satisfies that:

$$ \mid f(y)-f(x) \mid \leq \mid \nabla f (c) \cdot (y-x) \mid    $$

And I can't see how the inequality was used there, bacause by def, the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is:

$$ \mid \langle\,u,v\rangle  \mid   \leq  \mid\mid u \mid \mid  \cdot \mid\mid v \mid \mid   $$

And in the left when I use the MVT I have difference not a inner product

Comment: The first equation doesn't make sense. The function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. You used the MVT as if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, which is incorrect.

Comment: @zugzug It's correct that way. The "interval" $[x,y]$ is to be read as the line connecting $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R^n$. The equation is then obtained by simply applying the MVT and the chain rule to the function with $h(t):=f(x+tv)$, where $v$ is the unit vector pointing from $x$ to $y$. 
Though $f$ needs to be differentiable, not just continuous.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.